# Custom order pyspark dataframe usign a column

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe `df` :

I want to proprtize items based on `Type` column this order :  AAIC>AAFC>TBIC>TBFC and among them uisng `RANK` column i.e items with lower rank prioritzed within above order groups.
Any values in `Type` column other than AAIC or AAFC TBIC or TBFC I want to relabel them as `NON`

| ITEM | Type | RANK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAIC | 11 |
| 2 | AAFC | 8 |
| 3 | TBIC | 2 |
| 4 | TBFC | 1 |
| 5 | XYZ | 5 |
| 6 | AAIC | 7 |
| 7 | JHK | 10 |
| 8 | SWE | 3 |
| 9 | TBIC | 4 |
| 10 | AAFC | 9 |
| 11 | AAFC | 6 |

Desired pyspark dataframe `df` :-

| ITEM | Type | RANK | NEW_RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | AAIC | 7 | 1 |
| 1 | AAIC | 11 | 2 |
| 11 | AAFC | 6 | 3 |
| 2 | AAFC | 8 | 4 |
| 10 | AAFC | 9 | 5 |
| 3 | TBIC | 2 | 6 |
| 9 | TBIC | 4 | 7 |
| 4 | TBFC | 1 | 8 |
| 8 | NON | 3 | 9 |
| 5 | NON | 5 | 10 |
| 7 | NON | 10 | 11 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check this code:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

inputData = [
    (1, "AAIC", 11),
    (2, "AAFC", 8),
    (3, "TBIC", 2),
    (4, "TBFC", 1),
    (5, "XYZ", 5),
    (6, "AAIC", 7),
    (7, "JHK", 10),
    (8, "SWE", 3),
    (9, "TBIC", 4),
    (10, "AAFC", 9),
    (11, "AAFC", 6),
]
inputDf = spark.createDataFrame(inputData, schema=["item", "type", "rank"])

preprocessedDf = inputDf.withColumn(
    "type",
    F.when(
        F.col("type").isin(["AAIC", "AAFC", "TBIC", "TBFC"]), F.col("type")
    ).otherwise(F.lit("NON")),
).withColumn(
    "priority",
    F.when(F.col("type") == F.lit("AAIC"), 1).otherwise(
        F.when(F.col("type") == F.lit("AAFC"), 2).otherwise(
            F.when(F.col("type") == F.lit("TBIC"), 3).otherwise(
                F.when(F.col("type") == F.lit("TBFC"), 4).otherwise(F.lit(5))
            )
        )
    ),
)

windowSpec = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("priority", "rank")

preprocessedDf.withColumn("NEW_RANK", F.row_number().over(windowSpec)).drop(
    "priority"
).show()
```

Priorities for codes are hardcoded which may be hard to maintain in case of more values. You may want to adjust this part if it needs to be more flexible

I am moving all records to one partition to calculate the correct row_order. Its a common problem, its hard to calculate consistent ids with given order in distributed manner. If your dataset is big, there may be need to think about something else, probably more complicated

output:

```
+----+----+----+--------+
|item|type|rank|NEW_RANK|
+----+----+----+--------+
|   6|AAIC|   7|       1|
|   1|AAIC|  11|       2|
|  11|AAFC|   6|       3|
|   2|AAFC|   8|       4|
|  10|AAFC|   9|       5|
|   3|TBIC|   2|       6|
|   9|TBIC|   4|       7|
|   4|TBFC|   1|       8|
|   8| NON|   3|       9|
|   5| NON|   5|      10|
|   7| NON|  10|      11|
+----+----+----+--------+
```

Comment: Yes I was just about to add a note in question. The data set in about a million records and execution time goes up..would `dense_rank()` speed it up?

Comment: I think that it will be similar, imo the main problem here is the partitioning which is forcing us to process all records in one partition. For 1 kk records its not that terrible imo but if you need more concurrent solution we need to figure out something else ( i am not sure if this is possible)